# How to numerically solve a differential equation which has integration in it?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, integral-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation which has integration in it. It is not giving any results. Can anyone help?

```
F[t_, k_, \[Chi]_, x_] := 
  t^k*Sqrt[1 + (1817/2) t]/(1 + Exp[t - (\[Chi]/(x*10^7))]);
ODE = \[Chi]'[x] + 
    4*\[Pi]*x (((3/(4*\[Pi]))*
         HeavisideTheta[
          1.81712 - x]) - ((Sqrt[2]/\[Pi]^2)*1817^(3/
           2)*(Integrate[
            F[t, 1/2, \[Chi][x], x], {t, 
             0, \[Infinity]}] + ((1817)*(Integrate[
               F[t, 3/2, \[Chi][x], x], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]))))) == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{ODE, \[Chi][0] == 0}, \[Chi], {x, 0, 1.81712}];
Plot[Evaluate[\[Chi][x] /. First@sol], {x, 0, 1.81712}]
```

Comment: The integral does not seem to be  intergrable.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6rPY.png)

Comment: now i have edited it. It is integrable. how do you generally solve such differential equations?

Comment: Could you show how you integrated it? It is still not integrable. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qtu8.png)  without being able to integrate it, no point of going to the next step and use NDSolve.

Comment: that is the problem actually. I need to integrate it at each step since the differential equation is d\chi/dx.. So at each \chi and x , I need to find integration.

Comment: But you are using the thing you are trying to solve for, which is $\chi(x)$ in the integrand. So it is unknown. It is what you are solving for in the differential equation. So this will not work. it is like a catch 22.  to solve for it, you need to evaluate an integral which uses the solution. How could this work? At least I do not know. May be someone else will have an idea.

Comment: so this is bascially you have d\chi/dx=int[\chi]. so i know at x=0 \chi=0. hence i can calculate the integration. but how to do it that i am not able to understand. there should be some way.

Answer (score 3):

Some progress can be made as follows.  First, rescale `X` by `10^7` to avoid large values of `X` (at least at first). Then, because `X` and `x` appear only as a ratio in the integrands, define the functions,

```
f1[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[t + (1817/2) t^2]/(1 + Exp[t - y]), 
    {t, 0, Infinity]}, MaxRecursion -> 100]
f2[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[t Sqrt[t + (1817/2) t^2]/(1 + Exp[t - y]), 
    {t, 0, Infinity}, MaxRecursion -> 100]
```

Plots of these two functions are

[image]

[image]

and the ODE is solved by

```
xm = Rationalize[.001438, 0];
sol = NDSolveValue[{X'[x] + 4*π*x 10^-7 (3/(4*π) - 
    (Sqrt[2]/π^2*1817^(3/2)*(f1[X[x]/x] + (1817*(f2[X[x]/x]))))) == 0, 
    X[10^-8] == 0}, X[x], {x, 10^-8, xm}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
```

The lower bound of integration is set to `10^-8` to avoid division by zero at `x = 0`.  The upper bound is set to `0.001438`, because the solution blows up at about that value of `x`, as we see in to following plot.

```
Plot[sol, {x, 10^-8, xm}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, X}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

The explosive growth shown follows from the ODE and is not a numerical artifact, although accuracy deteriorates with this rapid growth.

**Approximate expressions for f1 and f2**

For `t` large relative to `2/1817`, `f1` can be approximated by

```
Integrate[Sqrt[1817/2] t/(1 + Exp[t - y]), {t, 0, Infinity}]
(* -Sqrt[1817/2] PolyLog[2, -E^y] *)
```

and similarly for `f2`

```
Integrate[Sqrt[1817/2] t^2/(1 + Exp[t - y]), {t, 0, Infinity}]
(* -2 Sqrt[1817/2] PolyLog[3, -E^y] *)
```

Unfortunately, this approximation does not help much in solving the ODE.

Comment: how did you plot X vs x. I tried this "Plot[X[x] /. sol, {x, 10^-8, xm}]" and got this error "ReplaceAll::reps: {6.02368*10^-7} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing."

Comment: @AKU I added the code that produces the final plot to my answer.  Note that I used `NDSolveValue`, not `NDSolve`, to produce `sol`.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, perhaps a starting point...

You could try to find an iterative solution (Picard iteration) using `NestList` starting with `\[Chi][x]=0`

```
sol = NestList[
  NDSolveValue[{\[Chi]'[x] + 
       4*\[Pi]*x (((3/(4*\[Pi])) ) - ((Sqrt[2]/\[Pi]^2)*1817^(3/
               2)*(NIntegrate[
               F[t, 1/2, #[x], x], {t, 
                0, \[Infinity]}] + ((1817)*(NIntegrate[
                  F[t, 3/2, #[x], x], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]))))) == 
      0, \[Chi][0] == 0}, \[Chi], {x, 0, 1.81712}] &, 0 &, 2]
```

Unfortunately only the first iteration evaluates!

Comment: I tried but as you said, it is not giving the desired result. BTW what is &,2 used for?

Comment: `&` defines a so called pure function, that' s a function without argument.   Where does your ode come from? Perhaps it's possible to modify the expression to get a convergent solution?

Comment: Oh okay. I have this analytical expression only. I do not know if we can do any modification to function F since this is the direct analytical expression we have.

Comment: Where do the integral-parts in your ode come from?

Comment: this is just an expression I am getting like this and it is present like this only.

Comment: I am getting the following error by using the same technique you mentioned. "NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (Sqrt[t] Sqrt[1+(1817 t)/2])/(1+E^(t-InterpolatingFunction[{<<1>>},{<<13>>},{<<1>>},{<<3>>},{<<1>>}][x]/(10000000 x))) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{\[Infinity],0.}}."

Comment: It looks like `\[Chi][x]` is yet defined ! Run my code with a fresh kernel.

Comment: no, still the same error.

Comment: My code runs with fresh kernel (Mathematica v12.2)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `StreamPlot`helps to understand the problem little bit better

```
F[t_, k_, \[Chi]_, x_] := t^k*Sqrt[1 + (1817/2) t]/(1 + Exp[t -(\[Chi]/(x*10^7))]);
int[z_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[F[t, k, z], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]

StreamPlot[{1, -4*\[Pi]*x (((3/(4*\[Pi]))*HeavisideTheta[1.81712 - x]) - 
((Sqrt[2]/\[Pi]^2)*1817^(3/2)*( int[ \[Chi] /x,1/2] + ((1817)*( int[ \[Chi] /x, 3/2] )))))}
, {x, 0.001, 1.81712 }, {\[Chi], -1, 1}, FrameLabel -> {x, \[Chi]}]
```

[image]

It looks like there is no "stable" solution!
Phaseplot also confirms @bbgodfrey's   *explosive growth observation*!